# Amazon EC2 as load balanced/failover solution

Tags: cloud

I'm thinking of an idea but not sure the pros/cons of it.

At the moment, we are hosting our website on a dedicated server. As a failover/load balanced solution, I'm thinking to use Amazon EC2+EBS.

The files can be rsync and mysql can be setup as master-master replication

When the load is high, I can up the machine, given sometime to "sync" and load balanced the traffic there.

is it do-able? any link I can read more on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to rely on EC2 as a backup, why use a "real server" at all?

You can do everything you've described here on EC2 and not need to worry about space/power/cooling/IPTransit/HWFailure/etc.

Comment: +1 There's really no reason for a dedicated server if you go for AWS.

Comment: Why waste the capital expenditure that they have already spent on the hardware? At least by using AWS as burst/failover he only has to pay for when he bursts/fails over. I can see that scenario when that hardware is old and outdated, or the vision changes, but for now, I think that he wants to know how he can use it as a secondary. Just my .02.

Comment: EC2 is way more expensive than hardware on the mid- to long-term (even considering periodical hardware updates).  using EC2 as backup/pike helper lets you keep those instances off most of the time and fire them up just when needed.  seems good sense to me

Answer (score 1):

This is very doable and a great idea if you have the server hardware but not the routing stuff and don't want to make the full switch to AWS. Check out this [guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_loadbalanced_apache_cluster). Just tweak some of it to your needs/what you already have.